# Programatically create content type for multilingual site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development

How to create content type for for multilingual site programatically.

Example Content type column internal name: firstName. English Display Name: First Name, German Display Name:Vorname. Same for all column name and content type name.

How can I do that?

Now how to create page layout from content type. As i am able to create page layout from content type. But for multiligual content type how can i do that? Below is my page layout module file. In that i have given content type name and content type id. But its not working

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="VdePageLayout" Url="_catalogs/masterpage" RootWebOnly="TRUE">
    <File Path="VdePageLayout\VdeArticalEventPageLayout.aspx" Url="VdeArticalEventPageLayout.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
      <Property Name="Title" Value="My Custom Page Layout" />
      <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_pagelayout_name;" />
      <Property Name="PublishingAssociatedContentType" Value=";#$Resources:vde_Page;#0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D00D6DCE36F9DE043FE925DBA1E365BB75B;#"
/>
    </File>
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

Comment: i know about create and delete content type. But how to create column with multilingual site with different display name and internal name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create [contenttypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460224%28v=office.14%29.aspx) by code or declarative.

First create site columns and then the contenttype.

Create a [feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee231541.aspx) that contains the columns and contenttype

If you want your columns multilingual you can [localize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955226.aspx) your site columns and 
contenttypes

For example a localized field:

```
     <Field
           ID="{350b1356-7fef-434b-8fa2-f83b837d9c6c}"
           Name="FirstName"       
           DisplayName="$Resources:field_firstName"
           Description="$Resources:field_firstName_description"
           Group="$Resources:field_group"
           Type="Note"
           Required="FALSE"
           NumLines="6" 
           RichText="TRUE"
           RichTextMode="Compatible">
      </Field>
```

The same for a contenttype

```
      <ContentType ID="0x0100491AD40E0BEC4799A4A2015691A853F2"
                   Name="$Resources:contenttype_xxx"
                   Description="$Resources:contenttype_x_description" 
                   Group="$Resources:contenttype_group" 
                   Inherits="TRUE" 
                   Version="0">
        <FieldRefs>
          <FieldRef ID="{350b1356-7fef-434b-8fa2-f83b837d9c6c}" 
                    Required="FALSE" Name="FirstName" NumLines="6" />
            </FieldRefs>
          </ContentType>
```

Comment: How to create page layout from multilingual content type? I am able to create page layout from simple content type. But as i am giving dynamic name of content type. I am not able to create page layout from it.

Comment: i have edited my question

Comment: hello it have been a while now, sorry i have one question if we have  Type="choice"for the field how can we do for the ressource File.